# Jackson JSON Parser - Specifying delimiter to serialize List of String

Tags: java, jackson

By default, a list of string `List<String>` will be serialized as "a,b,c", I want to serialize the list as "a;b;c" with semicolon as the delimiter. This only has to be on one property in a class. How can I do this?

Comment: You would have to join the `List` yourself and send it as a `String`. The JSON spec says arrays are csv.

Comment: You'll probably need to `@JsonSerialize(contentUsing=someClass.class)` here

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try @JsonSerialize annotation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `String.join(";", list)`